# How can I tell which init system Ansible runs when I use the "service" module?

Tags: ansible, init

From [the Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html), the service module:

> Controls services on remote hosts. Supported init systems include BSD init, OpenRC, SysV, Solaris SMF, systemd, upstart.

For a given machine, how can I tell which init system Ansible is using? A system may have init and systemd on it, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look into the modules' [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/system/service.py):

Inside `def main():`:

```
# Find service management tools
service.get_service_tools()
```

Then to `class LinuxService(Service):` and to `def get_service_tools(self):`

```
    # Locate a tool to enable/disable a service
    if check_systemd():
        # service is managed by systemd
        ...
    elif location.get('initctl', False) and os.path.exists("/etc/init/%s.conf" % self.name):
        # service is managed by upstart
        ...
    elif location.get('rc-service', False):
        # service is managed by OpenRC
        ...
    elif self.svc_initscript:
        # service is managed by with SysV init scripts
        ...
```

I've cut some code, but this snippet should answer your question: what system Ansible is likely to choose if there are many.

Systemd is the first one to search, then upstart, etc...

Comment: I think it is not a good idea. On my Ubuntu 14 server, I have systemd installed but not used for init. The result is that Ansible tries to use Systemd instead of Upstart (the system declared service manager)

Answer (score 22):

The init system on a host is available as Ansible fact `ansible_service_mgr`.

Comment: This is inconsistent between ansible versions. I have Ubuntu trusty systems where Ansible 2.2.1 reports "upstart" and Ansible 2.4 reports "service".

Comment: Great. Now the next newbie question...how to do the right ansible task based on this fact...

Comment: You need to add an [when conditional](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) to the task like this: ′when: ansible_service_mgr == "systemd"′

Comment: Incorrect ansible_service_mgr issue is fixed: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30753